# Using glob.glob to find files in multiple folders through a given path?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to use glob.glob to to go through a user-given path to Python and then finding all subsequent folders for a .txt. Currently, below, is what I have but it doesn't seem to work.

```
fileName = raw_input("> ")
listOfTxt = []
for files in glob.glob(os.path.join(fileName, "\\Folder\\*\\*\\*.txt")):
     listOfTxt.append(files) # add it to the list
```

I'm not sure how to get this to work, or I'm just not understanding the glob.glob with os.path.

Comment: Do you want to get all `.txt` files under `user_dir/Folder`, or do you want all `.txt` files two directories below `user_dir/Folder`?

Comment: Consider raw string literals - they are so much easier to read (`r"\Folder\*\*\*.txt"`) than all those doubled backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want a list of all `.txt` files in `os.path.join(user_dir,'Folder')`, then `os.walk` is probably a better way to go:

```
 import os
 user_dir = os.path.join(raw_input('> '),'Folder')
 file_list = [ ]
 for dirpath,_,filenames in  os.path.walk(user_dir):
     for name in filenames:
         if name.endswith('.txt'):
             file_list.append(os.path.join(user_dir,dirpath,name))
```

Comment: Ah this worked for me! Thank you. I'm not sure exactly what I was trying to do, I had it a certain way before but then had to change it for when the python file was not in the same location as all of the other files. So this worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  I'm happy to be useful

Answer (score 0):

you join the given name with a path, which is strange and probably not what you want.
You probably want something like

```
glob.glob(os.path.join("\\Folder\\*\\*\\",fileName+".txt"))
```

?

Comment: I don't totally understand what the OP wants to accomplish as of yet, but this doesn't achieve the stated goals of searching "a user-given path" for ".txt" files.